# Can't change permission for bash.bashrc file in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chmod, bashrc

I'm trying to change the permission for my .bashrc file in Ubuntu but don't seem to have permission. I've tried following the [example here](http://catcode.com/teachmod/chmod_cmd2.html):

```
Open up publicity.html for reading and writing by anyone.

Before:  -rw-r--r--  publicity.html
Command: chmod og=rw publicity.html
After:  -rw-rw-rw-  publicity.html
```

Here's my terminal session:

```
username@ubuntu:/etc$ -rw-r--r-- bash.bashrc
-rw-r--r--: command not found
username@ubuntu:/etc$ chmod og=rw bash.bashrc
chmod: changing permissions of `bash.bashrc': Operation not permitted
username@ubuntu:/etc$ -rw-rw-rw- bash.bashrc
-rw-rw-rw-: command not found
```

Any ideas how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is probably not owned by you. try

```
sudo chmod og=rw bash.bashrc
```

You can see who owns it with

```
ls -l
```

and you can change owner with

```
sudo chown username:username bash.bashrc
```

Comment: Fantastic. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you entered `-rw-r--r-- bash.bashrc` as a command.
It's not a command itself but is part the output of the command `ls -l bash.bashrc`.
**Example:**

```
user@host:~$ ls -l /etc/bash.bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1939 2010-04-19 04:15 /etc/bash.bashrc
```

See Wikipedia for further information on the meaning of `-rw-r--r--` 
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Symbolic_notation